# Перекрестные SQL запросы

Tags: запрос, sql-server, sql

Имеется 3 запрос. Запрос 1 выводит 12 значений, запрос 2-11 и 3й -10. Как совместить их в 1 таблицу? Как я понял, необходимо использовать перекрёсные запросы, но не могу понять как это выполнить, помогите.

```
  -------запрос1
select sp2.NAIM
from sp2
inner join kdk1 on kdk1.kk02=sp2.kod_n
where sp2.SPR='k02'
group by sp2.naim
-------запрос 2
select count(KDK1.n_kdk) from KDK1 inner join sp2 on sp2.KOD_N=kdk1.KK02 
                                    inner join KDK on kdk.N_KDK=KDK1.N_KDK
                                    where sp2.SPR='k02' and kdk.kpol=1
                                    group by sp2.NAIM  
--------запрос 3
select count(KDK1.n_kdk) from KDK1 inner join sp2 on sp2.KOD_N=kdk1.KK02 
                                    inner join KDK on kdk.N_KDK=KDK1.N_KDK
                                    where sp2.SPR='k02' and kdk.kpol=2
                                    group by sp2.NAIM
```

Comment: я же вам написал [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/295920/t-sql-количекство-строк-в-sql). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77658/1

    select sp2.NAIM, 
      sum(iif(kdk.kpol = 1,1,0)) as male, 
      sum(iif(kdk.kpol = 2,1,0)) as female
    from KDK 
      inner join SP2 on sp2.KOD_N=KDK.KK02 
    where 
      sp2.SPR='k02'
    group by sp2.naim

Answer (score 1):

Не вполне понятно, что вы понимаете под "совместить". Такой операции нет в SQL. :-)
Лучше слов - показать желаемый результат.
Возможно так:

```
select sp2.NAIM ...

UNION ALL

select cast(count(KDK1.n_kdk) as varchar)...

UNION ALL

select cast(count(KDK1.n_kdk) as varchar)...
```

Тогда так, если не вникать:

```
select X.naim, y.cnt, z.cnt from
(
select sp2.NAIM 
from sp2
inner join kdk1 on kdk1.kk02=sp2.kod_n
where sp2.SPR='k02'
group by sp2.naim
) X
left join
(select count(KDK1.n_kdk), sp2.NAIM from KDK1 inner join sp2 on sp2.KOD_N=kdk1.KK02 
                                    inner join KDK on kdk.N_KDK=KDK1.N_KDK
                                    where sp2.SPR='k02' and kdk.kpol=1
                                    group by sp2.NAIM  
) y on x.naim = y.naim
left join
(select count(KDK1.n_kdk), sp2.NAIM from KDK1 inner join sp2 on sp2.KOD_N=kdk1.KK02 
                                    inner join KDK on kdk.N_KDK=KDK1.N_KDK
                                    where sp2.SPR='k02' and kdk.kpol=2
                                    group by sp2.NAIM
) z on x.naim = z.naim
```

Comment: спасибо, но нет, результат каждого запроса должен быть в отдельном столбце.

Comment: http://rghost.ru/52357371  вот такой должен быть результат

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Может вам нужен full join.